# Does iOS 7 provide a way to set a bundle display name plist value for VoiceOver?

Tags: iphone, ios, accessibility, voiceover

Our app has a name that is an abbreviation. For VoiceOver we want to set a different string so it reads the app name correctly.

Did Apple introduce a new info.plist key for this?

Comment: FWIW, I tried a number of ways to get around this - inserting thin spaces, zero width spaces, etc.  The only thing that seemed to work is inserting *actual* spaces.  Did you ever figure out something that would work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Apple introduced any new elements to info.plist.

This is not possible for the time being to have distinct visible and accessible titles.